Why “nouveau riche” but “art nouveau?”
In English, why are the adjectives in different places in nouveau riche and art nouveau? Is that an artifact of the original French, a corruption in adoption, or something else?
(Apologies if this is a better fit at the French site.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The word order is unrelated to English, both art nouveau and nouveau riche are set expressions in French.
Art nouveau could have been equally called nouvel art but the first form was picked for some reason1. On the other hand, riche nouveau wouldn't work as riche would be understood as an adjective and nouveau as a noun, something like 'rich newcomer'.
Some modern versions of art nouveau are aptly called in French nouvel art nouveau and should a newer kind of nouveau riche appear, it would be called nouveau nouveau riche :-)
1 A potential nuance between both forms is that art nouveau is more like 'art renewed', a new trend in art in general, encompassing painting, architecture, sculpture, etc. (similar to art moderne), while nouvel art might be something completely new, a new form of art previously unknown. Cinema, known as 'the seventh art', qualifies as a nouvel art.
